# Develop an application in java For different screen resolutions

Tags: java, swing

I am a c# developer. Now, I want to learn java and want to create a desktop application in Java.

The application that I want to create using Java is a line of business application. In simple terms, the application will have some textboxes, labels, comboboxes & datagrid and it will mainly be CRUD operations.

Now, I would like to know that what tools should I use to fulfill my below mentioned requirements:

1. Which is the latest tool to develop java applications? In c# we used Visual Studio
2. What should I use? I mean Swing or Java FX or might be something else? Because once I complete my project it will be installed on different computers with different sized screens and different screen resolutions. In .Net we used WPF. In WPF we have some layout containers like Grid & Wrap Panel etc... So by using those containers properly we can have a good application that looks almost similar in any screen resolution and on any sized screen.

Comment: Java FX has many things in common with WPF (or should I say, they just adopted many of the WPF concepts). I easily ported a complex WPF control library to FX without thinking too much about restructuring the code. We have also successfully recreated a non-trivial WPF application in FX. There are a few WPF things that you will be missing, like DataTemplates or the way Styles work, but if you like WPF, you may also like FX. Besides that, we're using NetBeans as IDE.

Comment: @Clemens Thanks for the helping hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can use either Eclipse or IntelliJ, both are great
2. JavaFX definitely! It gives you more options, and its very html & CSS friendly (yes, you can use this for desktop apps), great for on-the-fly image scaling, so different resolution will be easily handled with it. If you combine it with bootstrap, you'll have an easy job

For example:

```
Button buttonColor = new Button("Color");
buttonColor.setStyle("-fx-background-color: slateblue; -fx-text-fill: white;");
```

You get this:

[image: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/img/button_style_inline.png]

Of course, you can place this in css file and then use it:

```
#font-button {
    -fx-font: bold italic 20pt "Arial";
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( one-pass-box , black , 8 , 0.0 , 2 , 0 );
}
```

and then:

```
Button buttonFont = new Button("Font");
buttonFont.setId("font-button");
```

results in:

[image: Image2]

Comment: Sorry, I think I forgot to mention that I am creating a desktop application & not a web application.

Comment: All I said is for desktop app! :) I've done two such with JavaFX, and its better to use css, code is much cleaner, it looks way better and with with bootstrap I don't care about screen resolution. And I say this as primarily backend developer...

Comment: Sorry sir but I think you are still misunderstanding me or I am misunderstanding you. What I mean by desktop application is that a stand alone application. For example notepad++. So, is it possible to use css and HTML in such non-browser based apps???

Comment: Yes you can. there's even an IDE build with web tech. https://atom.io/

Comment: Yes Vishal it is! :)  I updated my answer with some example.

Comment: Heres one example of handling desktop app with css styles: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UD_SJ07mQlM But I recommend using bootstrap elements for multi screen size handling, since well, its meant for it.

Comment: Thank you for great answer!!!!!!!

Comment: I forgot the best part: unlike creating web sites, you don't have to worry about different browsers and its versions, since JavaFX has its own html and css processor and its standardized, so different java versions will not break what you wrote.